# Python Socket - Test for devices with Telnet enable

Tags: python, sockets

I have a bunch of devices that I have to do an script to know if telnet is enable or not. So I did the following script:

```
import socket

file = open('list', 'r')
file = file.readlines()
list = []
port = 23 


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


for i in file:
    i=i.replace('\n','')
    list.append(i)
for i in host:
    try:
        s.connect((i, port))
        s.shutdown(2)
        print (i+' Telnet is enable') 
    except:
        print (i+' Telnet is disable')
```

The problem is that after the first test that show telnet is enable, all of the devices are showing as been disable. I check the error that I get and the error is the following:

```
socket.error: (133, 'Transport endpoint is already connected')
```

I know that has to do with closing the first session, but I'm not able to. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13110002/477878

Comment: Why not just [`close`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) the connection?

Comment: if I do s.close() and then I try to open a new one, I get this error 'socket.error: (9, 'Bad file descriptor')'

Comment: @amb1s1 You'll need to close the old socket and _create a new one_, ie put the `s = socket.socket(...` inside the loop.

Comment: doing s.close() is not closing the old socket?

Comment: I see, I have to have the s = socket.socket(... in the loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

You'll need to close the old socket and create a new one, ie put the s = socket.socket(... inside the loop. –  Joachim Isaksson