# Try to connect socket until server starts in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want in AsyncTask  my app to try to connect to server until the connection is done. If the server is running when i start the app, it works, but if i start tha app and then i start the server it says: java.io.IOException: fcntl failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

```
public class FetchData extends AsyncTask {
        BufferedReader in;
        InetSocketAddress socketAddress;
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.158", 9999);

            while(!_socket.isConnected()) {
                try {

                    _socket.connect(socketAddress);
                    Log.d("socket_status", "Socket is connected!");
                    break;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("socket_status", e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

UPDATE: _socket is created in onCreate method @Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_widget);

    if(_socket == null)
        _socket = new Socket();
-----------------------
}
```

Comment: Have you added the Internet permission to the manifest?

Comment: Yes i did. If i just connect with `_socket.connect(socketAddress)` and the server is running, it works fine. The problem is only when i start the app, server is not running and when i start the server, nothing happens. it just loops and throws that exception.

Comment: You are not even showing where and when you create the socket. The solution is to create every time a new socket in the catch block.

Comment: Creating a new socket didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem: [Does socket become unusable after connect() fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109899/does-socket-become-unusable-after-connect-fails)

I had to create a new socket in the catch or finally block.