# Why isn't SO_REUSEADDR letting my take over a connection in TIME_WAIT?

Tags: c++, windows, winsock

This isn't my actual code, of course, but it's a minimally-sized example to demonstrate the issue I'm having.

```
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<ws2tcpip.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
    bool iOptVal = true;

    WSADATA wsaData = { 0 };
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    SOCKET s1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    SOCKET s2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    struct sockaddr_in local_addr;
    memset(&local_addr, 0, sizeof local_addr);
    local_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x7f000001); // 127.0.0.1
    local_addr.sin_port = htons(52685);

    setsockopt(s1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&iOptVal, sizeof(bool));
    setsockopt(s2, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&iOptVal, sizeof(bool));

    bind(s1, (sockaddr *)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr));
    printf("bind(s1) returned error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    bind(s2, (sockaddr *)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr));
    printf("bind(s2) returned error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    connect(s1, (sockaddr *)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr));
    printf("connect(s1) returned error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    connect(s2, (sockaddr *)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr));
    printf("connect(s2) returned error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    shutdown(s1, SD_BOTH);
    printf("shutdown(s1) returned error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    closesocket(s1);
    printf("closesocket(s1) returned error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    connect(s2, (sockaddr *)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr));
    printf("connect(s2) returned error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
```

From what I understand, most of the calls should return 0, except for the first attempt to connect `s2`, because the connection is actively being used by `s1`. But instead of letting me takeover from `TIME_WAIT` the second time, it returns a second error 10048.

Comment: Which call returns the error?

Comment: You are not doing valid error handling. This code is completely ignoring all function return values, and blindly calling `WSAGetLastError()` whether an error actually occurred or not. `WSAGetLastError()` is only valid when a function return value says it is valid. You MUST check return values! And BTW, a TCP socket can't `connect()` to the same address it `bind()`s to. You need a `listen()`ing socket bound to an adress, and then have another socket `connect()` to it

Comment: @RemyLebeau Like I said, this isn't the real code. The actual code, which I'm not at liberty to share, includes things like error handling. This is just a minimized example to illustrate the behavior I'm witnessing.

Comment: @BenVoigt I believe the final connect call should succeed, because SO_REUSEADDR lets you take over in TIME_WAIT, but it's returning WSAEADDRINUSE, like when the connection was actively being used by s1.

Comment: You're calling `connect` twice on `s2`, of course the last one fails.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/13109899/103167