# Client Calling connect() without server calling listen()

Tags: c, sockets, client, listen

I have a normal server and client TCP C program that uses sockets.
It works perfectly when server is started first (i.e. server calls `listen()` and then waits for client to call `connect()`).

Now, what I want to implement is a situation where the client is started first, and the server is started at any later time.

The client should keep trying to connect to the server. Until server is OFF, I know that the client's `connect()` call will return -1; but the client should keep trying until a successful connection is established.

Currently on the client side, I am trying to call `connect()` in a `while` loop but it will not work if server isn't already listening when the client runs.

Client connect code:

```
while( 1)
    {
        
        for(int j=0; j<argc-3; j++){
            //sockfd of each server needed to be connect()ed is stored in array all_sock_fd[]

            if ((sender_conn=connect(all_sock_fd[j], (struct sockaddr *)&all_sockaddrs[j],sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)) {
                
                //do nothing if fails
            }
            else{ //if connection successful then create a thread for that connection
                if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL ,  you_connect_to_others , (void*) &all_sock_fd[j]) < 0)
                {
                    perror("could not create thread");
                    return 1;
                }
                
            }
        }
}
```

The code above works fine when Servers are `listen()`-ing already before client calls `connect()`.
But if the client is run before the server (i.e. if server starts 2 seconds after client) then this code will never connect.

I tried the `while` loop approach where the client keeps trying to call `connect()` hoping that when server finally calls `listen()`, a connection will be established.

But this does not work. Even when server is turned ON after the client, The connection never happens.

Can I use `select()` or `poll()` for this? If so , how?

Comment: You can't reconnect a socket, even if a prior connect failed. You have to close it and recreate it. If a system call fails you should always examine *why,* by testing or printing the `errno` or its message (derived from `perror()` or `strerror()`). If you had done that you would have discovered the problem for yourself.

Comment: And no, you don't need `select()` or `poll()`. You just need to read what I had already written 15 minutes before you posted that edit.

Comment: Related:dupe: [Does socket become unusable after connect() fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109899/)

Comment: i understand that i need to read the error, but how would  knowing the error help me reconnect?

Comment: I recommend [0MQ](https://zeromq.org/). With this library you can implement in very few lines programs, where the client connect first and then the server goes online, etc. Very powerful networking and messaging library.

Comment: @user207421 so? And what is your point? You can still recommend things to people even when they do not explicitly ask for recommendations. I see no point in your objection as I'm recommending something that is related to the OPs question and might solve his/her problem. The OP is free to ignore my recommendation.

Comment: The point is that he isn't asking for recommendations, and secondly that what you are recommending here amounts to using a hammer to crack a nut, as opposed to adding a couple of lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct. However, you need to close and recreate the socket on each loop iteration (see [Does socket become unusable after connect() fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109899/)), eg:

```
for(int j = 0; j < argc-3; j++){
    //sockfd of each server needed to be connect()ed is stored in array all_sock_fd[]
    int sockfd;
    while (1)
    {
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create socket");
            return 1; 
        }

        sender_conn = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&all_sockaddrs[j], sizeof(all_sockaddrs[j]));
        if (sender_conn == 0) break;

        // examine errno and decide whether it is reasonable to continue retrying

        close(sockfd);

        //wait a few seconds and try again
        sleep(5);
    }

    //connection successful, create a thread for that connection
    all_sock_fd[j] = sockfd;
    if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, you_connect_to_others, (void*) &all_sock_fd[j]) < 0)
    {
       perror("could not create thread");
       close(all_sock_fd[j]);
       all_sock_fd[j] = -1;
       return 1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You right me crazy ;-)